# Dirt next to mouse pointer icon

Tags: linux, mouse, arch-linux

I am using Arch Linux. Sometimes the icon of the mouse pointer changes and pixels appear like dirt on the right of the arrow. [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXjuJ.jpg) and [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgl9b.jpg) show the problem.

The issue disappears after reboot. 
I suspect this to happen after an intensive use of resources but I am not sure at all.

This is the version of my environment:

```
$ pacman -Qs | grep cinnamon
local/cinnamon 3.4.3-1
local/cinnamon-control-center 3.4.0-1
local/cinnamon-desktop 3.4.2-1
local/cinnamon-menus 3.4.0-1
local/cinnamon-screensaver 3.4.1-2
local/cinnamon-session 3.4.1-1
local/cinnamon-settings-daemon 3.4.2-1
local/cinnamon-translations 3.4.3-1
```

---

***pic1***:

[image]

***pic2***:

[image]

Comment: Have you updated your graphics drivers?

Comment: I've seen it happen on Windows sometimes (very rarely). A reboot would make the issue disappear for a very long time.

Comment: Try the advice in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723683/mouse-cursor-leaving-trails-artifacts).

Answer (score 4):

This is called screen tearing or wallpaper tearing

create /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
and add this snippet
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection

If symptoms persist try this also
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection

Both snippets are taken from the Archwiki Intel page

Of course, you must reboot your system afterwards.